# I don't see any output with Aquamacs

Tags: aquamacs

I'm trying to compile a pdfLatex with Aquamacs but I don't see any output. These are the shorts cuts I've used:

C-x C-f

Aqmc ask me to select a title for my project I've typed : "test.tex"

C-c, C-e

Then press Enter twice:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
test test test test test test test
\end{document}
```

C-c C-c

And then: C-c, C-l  but I don't see nothing. No error no file. Where is my error?

Comment: Click on the LaTeX icon in order to compile the document.

Comment: I've done it but nothing...

Comment: Did you install MacTeX?

Comment: I feel very stupid, no I didn't....Thanks a lot @egreg you save me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org) is a porting of Emacs to the Mac OS X interface. Installing it doesn't provide with a TeX distribution.

So you need to install a TeX system; my recommended choice is the *full* [MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex) that installs the current release of TeX Live. Installing the basic version is possible, but then it forces you to chase after package sets when you need a TeX package that's not present in the basic set.

TeX Live is also provided by MacPorts and Fink, but these distributions suffer from the same problems as the Debian provided ones: you can't update packages with `tlmgr`, but have to wait till the distributors of MacPorts and Fink decide to update their package sets.

Instead, MacTeX installs also TeX Live Utility, which makes it very easy to frequently updating your TeX distribution.